# When does an Akka Actor receive a message in its mailbox when sent from a loop

Tags: java, akka

I have noticed when I have an Actor that is sending messages from a loop (traversing through and creating a message for each item and sending the message to another actor) like the following

```
for(int x = 0; x <= 15_000; x++){
  ......
  //Create message 
  //send message to another actor
}
```

The other Actor does not receive any messages until the loop has completed?  Can someone explain why this is happening or where should I look for an explanation. I have used the tell method and ask method to do this and the behavior is the same.

Comment: You probably shouldn't be coding your Actors in a way such that it matters when the messages are received. Your code in one Actor should work fine, so long as its messages are received "sometime later". Or are you just worried about performance?

Comment: Yes performance is my concern.

Comment: I would guess that it is that your loop is quick and all messages are enqueued into the mailbox of the other actor before it happens to process any of them.

Comment: This question does not contain enough detail to answer it: how are you concluding that the other Actor does not start processing?

Comment: I have put a break point in the other actor and I am also viewing the logs.  Another thing I did was put the actor to sleep for 5 seconds after sending the message. When putting the thread to sleep I can see the other actor receives the message and processes each message after it is sent.  If I remove the Thread.sleep code nothing is processed until the loop completes.

Comment: @Patrik the loop took about 13 seconds to complete.

Comment: if it takes 13 seconds you are doing something else than sending a few messages (I don't know what 15_000 is)

Comment: no I am not doing anything but creating messages and sending them to another actor.  15_000 is 15k  in java.  I am using the new support for underscores since java 7 http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/underscores-literals.html